# Predict Test Sample Response for SVM Regression

Tags: matlab, regression, svm, curve-fitting, predict

I am running test on data samples using the example of SVM Regression Model, in the case of the example given in this MathWorks documentation (link: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/compactregressionsvm.predict.html#buvytaz) the training data needs to have the same number of rows as the predict data, this is required so far to be able to run the prediction. What can I do if my data varies from the number of rows? How can I train my support vector machine with a data that have different number of samples and still be able to predict with the consequence of having maybe bigger error?

```html
Data sample of the training data for the model and the data that I want to use for Mdl = fitrsvm. 
ans=10×2 table
    Training data    Data to predict
    ___________    ____________
          14             9.4833    
          27             28.938    
          10              7.765    
          28                 
          22             21.054    
          29             31.484    
        24.5             30.306    
        18.5                  
          32             28.225    
          28
```

Step by step verification of what I wanted to do:
What I did was: 
1. Built a model
[image: 0. So far so good] 
2. Test it with YFit
[image: 1. tbl so far so good]
3. Modify the table and it did work!. 
[image: 2. just added the same row on the top of tbl]
4. I doubled the size of the table to predict and it did work!.
[image: 3. doubling the row of tbl and it worked]
I did something wrong before.

Answer (score 0):

You can't train your model with unlabelled data, i.e. that has no "predict" value. I would suggest you just filter out all the unlabelled data points and train the model on this subset.

From intuition this just represents the fact, that you cannot learn from these data points. If I want to learn the relationship between age -> income, it does not help me at all to ask someone JUST their age and not their income. The information is useless to answer my question.

Comment: thank you for your reply. The thing is that I would like to use the SVR model to predict other data that was no originally in the data set. How to do this?attached is a example case: <img src="https://drive.google.com/open?id=1yEqoG1qERFzXleWmQC2zmG2A0yTXxU7A">

Comment: Your example is very simple: There is one feature and one label. What can you do with that? You are doing supervised learning. So you tell your model for a certain number of features, what the label is. For the trained you need both informations!
Now: If you have just the feature, your trained model can predict the value of the label for some data.
Somehow you have your data mixed up. If you want to predict values on the left hand side, that means the values of your left hand are your labels.

Comment: I am actually following Matlab steps, so in the case of the labels I am turning my array into table and the conversion process adds labels to all columns [image](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gzHSJQ7hGoGwyheHzE3dFgeLInC2lwdF).When I do the training I just specify the column label that I need, this is `Mdl = fitrsvm(tbl(idxTrn,:),'matrix13','Standardize',true);%create the SVR model`
So far I have been able to predict the values when I give `YFit` the same format of the original table but, how can I give `YFit` data that was not originally in table but I still need to predict?

Comment: In the example: 
YFit = predict(Mdl,tbl(idxTest,:));
YFit is the output of the the predict function. You do not give it a format, you get it in a certain format. I just don't understand, what you want to do here.
Can you maybe post a complete runnable code snippet? At what line does something not work and what is the behaviour vs. your expected behaviour?

Comment: Thanks for following up. My bad, sorry. What I did was: 1. Buil a model, 2. Test it with `YFit`, 3. Modify the table and it did work!. I did something wrong before. I already modified the post showing each result.